# How can i give permission to a user, so can write, read and delete on all the folders?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, user

I am configuring a server with dirrent aplications on it, but for accessing by ftp, i can't use root user, so i made another one to acces from filezilla, but i noticed that i have no permission to make nothing anywhere, i've read to give permissions to an specific folder, but im not gonna give me permission on every single folder of the server, so, is there any way to give my user permission on all the folders at once?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you want a **group** permission.

Comment: But, i don't have any group of users, its just mine, one that is not root, for using ftp

Comment: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/

Comment: Of course you have a group of users.  It's Linux.. Add the user in question to the ***wheel group***.  Then they will be allowed to `sudo` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `sudo chown -R username: <directory>`
2. `chmod -R ug=rw,o=r <directory>`

Comment: I would like to give those permitions to every folder at once, as root have, how can i do this?

Comment: What FS do the drives have? If they're `ext4`, you can do `sudo chmod ugo+wx /path/to/drive`. Please keep in mind that the 'o' in `ugo` means 'others', which can be a security issue. If the files were created on another OS, like Windows, you should `cd /path/to/drive` and then `sudo chown -R -v your_username:your_username *`. Please let me know if it worked so that I can update my answer in order to help future people with the same issue.